# blender 3.0 rotate move selection acording to its direction

Tags: modeling

I try to move/rotate a selection base on its direction. On previous blender I used to press 2 times the axis I wanted to change and it goes "local" orientation.

[image]

On 3.0 I can't figure out how to do it like on the image. I have tried to change the `transformation orientation` to gobal, local, etc. None of these options do the trick

If I do a new project, the problem is the same (notice the local transform info at the top left corner, proving I am in local transform).
[image]

Comment: And what are your object rotations?

Comment: 0 0 0, I have created a cube, then go edit mode then rotate, then I try G + X * 2 (like in your gif)

Comment: Hmm, maybe some setting is responsible for losing that double tap ability...

Comment: no, as you can see on the screenshot, it says "local", still the red line is along the x-axis line

Answer (score 1):

This still works - press an axis letter twice to change the transform orientation:

[image]

Keep in mind it alternates between local and world space, it doesn't automatically create a custom orientation based on the currently selected element:

[image]

You can create a custom orientation based on a selected face or edge

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, maybe something is off with my blender 3.0 but that doest work (I tried with a simple cube as a new object) the action on the top left tells me global then local when I press 2 time, but nothing change in the view and the movement is the same

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my post